# While recording a sound, how can I know if the source of the sound is from the built-in microphone or headphone microphone?

Tags: iphone, sdk

There is such a question in odesk's iPhone Programming OS 2.1 Test, and I couldn't find answer for it in developer documentation.

Possible answer options:

(a) With the NSSound class method named audioSource
wrong, class exists on macos only, and there is no method audioSource in it.

(b) With the AudioQueueGetParameters function
wrong. There is AudioQueueGetParameter function. Without ending s. Misprint? Function exists both on macosx and ios. Documentation is unclear and says: "In Mac OS X v10.5, audio queues have one parameter available: kAudioQueueParam_Volume, which controls playback gain." AudioQueue.h gives 4 more constants, but they can't help us with the question.

(c) Be querying the registry
no comment

(d) By polling for audio events
no idea

(e) iPhone OS 2.1 version doesn't support sound recording

what is correct answer and why?

**Edit:**
Do you know an answer which will work in later iOS versions - give it. I don't know answer either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing something related to OS 2.1 seeing as we are currently on iOS 6? Lots of things have changed or have been removed.

Comment: @Nick Bull, I am interested because I don't know an answer in either iOS version. And many things were added since iOS 2.1 but core thing are kept unchanged since then.

Comment: But the answer for this might be completely different to the new version and so if you had to write something now, you would then have to find the answer for that. Very small market for OS 2.1 apps these days.

Comment: Nick, wanna just to chat? If you know answer which will work in later iOS versions - give it.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the answer is "E":
- Reason: iPhone OS 3.0 :- AVAudioRecorder provided the first
  Objective-C approach for recording sound. It offers a simple way to
  record sound to a file but doesn't allow processing of the sound
  on-the-fly (for that, AudioQueueNewInput is still required).
- Reference:
  http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/03/history-of-ios-media-apis-iphone-os-20.html